# Find image width, height and start and end points

Tags: javascript, swift

There is a given 2d image array as follows.
I need to find start and end index of 0'z and also width and height.

I have implemented my approach as follows, but I wonder how it could be done more effectively or with few line codes. Javascript or swift solutions are fine.

Zeros always form a rectangle or square.

```
var image: [[Int]] = 
    [
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    ]

func findZeros (input : [[Int]]) -> (x : Int, y: Int, width:Int, height:Int)
{
  var x = 0;
  var y =  0;
  var width = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var isWidthSet = false;

  for row in 0...input.count-1
  {
    if width != 0
    {
       isWidthSet = true
    }
    for column in 0...input[row].count-1
    {
      if input[row][column] == 0
      {
        if (x == 0 && y == 0)
        {
          x = row
          y = column
        }
        total += 1
        if isWidthSet == false
        {
            width += 1
        }
      }
    }
  }    

  return (x,y,width,total/width)
}

print(findZeros(input:image))
```

Comment: You really need to be posting your code reviews at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead of here.

Comment: What if the zeros do not form a rectangle?

Comment: It always forms a rectangle.

Comment: Your code computes a wrong y-coordinate for `[ [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1] ]`

Comment: What do you propose Martin?

Answer (score 0):

My 50 cents using `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` to avoid nested loops:

```js
function findProps(image) {
  var p = {x1: -1, y1: -1, x2: -1, y2: -1};
  
  for (var t = 0; t <= image.length >> 1;) {
    p.x1 = image[t].indexOf(0);
    p.x2 = image[t].lastIndexOf(0);
    if (!~p.y1 && ~p.x1) p.y1 = t;
    var r = image.length - ++t;
    if (!~p.y2 && ~image[r].indexOf(0)) p.y2 = r;
    if (~p.y1 && ~p.y2) break;
  }
  p.exists = !!(~p.x1 && ~p.y1 && ~p.x2 && ~p.y2);
  p.width = p.exists + p.x2 - p.x1, 
  p.height = p.exists + p.y2 - p.y1;

  return p;
}

var img = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
];

console.log(findProps(img))
```